# Prevent GPS from using mobile data

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I have seen this question being asked many times in slightly different variations both on SO and other sites, but I have been unable to find anything that exactly answers what I want.

I have a program that gets GPS coordinates once every 30 minutes. It does not allow the providers to be network based, and sets `criteria.setCostAllowed(false);`. I have also removed the ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION permission to prevent finding less accurate coordinates via the network. Despite this, it uses an excessive amount of mobile data. I understand the concept of 'give the user a choice of network provider', but this is an internal app for my company and management's requirement is that no mobile data used whatsoever. How do I prevent mobile data usage?

Any solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't want it to use network location at all, why use criteria at all?  Just request GPS as the provider directly.

Comment: As @GabeSechan said, what you're doing now is still letting the system pick its own provider. Instead, directly only use the GPS provider, which is separated from any data usage. ps. Removing that permission will do you no good.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think of manually picking providers. Will test and check results, thanks.